# Tricky subset counting problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I had a combinatorics test today and I came upon this question which I just couldn't figure out how to do. Can anyone explain in depth how to do this?

> **Let** $m \ge 34$ be an **even** integer,
>   **Let** $n \ge 1$ be an integer.
>
> Consider the two sets
>
> $$
> \begin{gather} 
> \begin{aligned} 
> A &= \{1,2,\ldots,m\} \\ 
> B &= \{m+1,m+2,\ldots,m+n\}
> \end{aligned} \end{gather}
> $$
>
> **Let** $k$ be an integer with $17 \le k \le n+17$.
>
> Consider the subsets $X$ of $A \cup B$, such that $|X| = k$, $|X \cap A| = 17$, and all elements of $X \cap A$ **are even**.
>
> **How many such subsets are there?**
>
> **The answer is:** ${{m/2}\choose17} \cdot {{n}\choose{k-17}} $

I am having trouble figuring out what this means.

> Consider the subsets $X$ of $A \cup B$, such that $|X| = k$, $|X \cap A| = 17$, and all elements of $X \cap A$ **are even**.

I believe I will better understand this problem if I understand how to break down these set notations and get a more intuitive view of this problem which is easier to grasp.

Thank you!

Comment: If you know the answer, what's your question?

Comment: I do not know how to get to the answer.

Comment: Then you have to tell us where you are having trouble and what your thoughts are.

Comment: I do that for each question I ask, however this time around I do not know how to start. If you can offer hints, that will be an excellent contribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Consider the subsets $X$ of $A \cup B$, such that $|X| = k$, $|X \cap A| = 17$, and all elements of $X \cap A$ **are even**.

What this means in English is, the subset $X$ has $k$ elements and $17$ of these should be even elements from the set $A$. That's where ${m/2}\choose17$ comes from.

And for the rest of the elements ($k-17$ left), we should choose them from $B$ because we have already chosen $17$ elements from $A$ and the condition $|X \cap A| = 17$ is satisfied. So we can choose them with ${n}\choose{k-17}$. Then the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the "first" $17$ elements of $X$ must be chosen from $A$ and must be even, giving $ \binom{m/2}{17}$ways. Now we need to choose $k-17$ elements from $B$ ($B$ has cardinality $n$) so that is $\binom{n}{k-17}$. And we have $\color{red}{\binom{m/2}{17} \binom{n}{k-17}}$ in total.

Comment: Why are the "first" $17$ elements of $X$ chosen from $A$? Do you mind just breaking down this part: "Consider the subsets $X$ of $A \cup B$, such that $|X| = k$, $|X \cap A| = 17$, and all elements of $X \cap A$ **are even**."    I am assuming $A \cup B$ will be $\{1,2,...,m+n\}$ and the first $17$ elements happen to be the first $17$ elements in $A$? As far as $|X|=k$, and $|X \cap A|=17$ are concerned, I am not quite sure what those are.

Comment: $X=X_A \cup X_B$ where $X_A \subset A$ and $X_B \subset B$. $\mid X_A \mid =17$ and these elements are even and must be chosen from $A$. $ \mid X_B \mid =k-17$ and must be chosen $B$ which has cardinality $n$.